# practicing solidity to make tokens

Tags: tokens

PLZ share your knowledge. I'm a blockchain developer and i have just learnt soilidity but i dont have any previous experience with coding so i need a lot of practice to continue.
**MY QUESTION**
From where can i find more solidity problems or assignments to practice and enhance my ability ??? is there any online source available??
plz do reply any kind will be appreciated
THANK YOU

Comment: Id go with cryptozombies.io first, that should give you enough knowledge to start. Then just try creating your own simple projects. Thats how i learned anyways

Comment: I know this is not the answer you want, but  I wouldn't start from solidity: the language is not fundamentally harder than any other, but the ethereum virtual machine has a lot of caveats that developers faced in the 70-80's , or today if they actually manage low level memory... it's VERY hard even for a very expert developer.
this said, I'd start from something like python or javascript , just to understand how coding works.

Solidity is young, and as such it has a lot to refine (just think about how underflow/overflow changed in a few versions)

Comment: i do have the  understanding of javascript but i havent practised it enough so what do u recommend should i continue to practice javascript at first????

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.